# jQuery (document).ready(function($)

Tags: jquery

I wrote a jQuery script (below) and I used the (document).ready(function($)) function
does it slow down the website, and if it does than can you please show me a way to create such functions without slowing down the site?
Thank you very much!

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    $('#columns').wrapInner('<div id="columnsInner" />');
    $("div.productInfo:first").wrap("<div id='productDetails' />"); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Note that you can reduce that to `jQuery(function($) {`, or if you've not got a conflict on `$`, just `$(function() {`

Comment: If you are having performance problems with your site I would look somewhere else for the cause.

Comment: @Eric I once try'd reducing from jQuery to $ and for some odd reason it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply using `ready` will not have a significant performance impact.  A bigger issue is which selectors you use.  <s>For instance, "div.productInfo:first" should be fine on modern browsers with [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelector).</s>  However, on older browsers it may have to loop over divs until it finds a match.  You could avoid that if that div had an id.  I'm not necessarily advocating that; it's just a general consideration.

EDIT: Actually, I believe jQuery will not leverage querySelector(All), since it notes:

> Because :first is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :first cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. To achieve the best performance when using :first to select
>   elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then
>   use .filter(":first")."

So even for newer browsers, it would be better to use:

```
$("div.productInfo").filter(":first")
```

jQuery would still have to loop over the divs in older browsers.

Comment: "it may have to loop over all divs." - seems unlikely. I think sizzle.js is clever enough to stop once it finds the first one.

Comment: Thank you. but is it even if the code is like this $('#rightColumn').insertBefore('#center-right-wrapper'); ?

Comment: @Eric, I thought that was implied.  You still have to loop over half on average.

Comment: @Hersh, id selectors (#) should perform will in all browsers.